# Local Data on Webserver

Tags: php, mysql, database, local

I am currently thinking up a system to allow for online voting system for my old high school (a mock award ceremony really). Due to a restrictive school board I can guarentee that MySQL will not be an option to store votes. I am also under the assumption that should votes be stored in local files, data will overwrite when the file is called multiple times at the same time (which is a large possibility).

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I might go about this? Perferably a PHP based solution as for the school board's restrictions. Please note the data will only need to be accessible for a few hours on a continuously running web server, so if the data is RAM-like (for a lack of a better term) that would be fine.

Comment: Your school board gets to determine which database technology you use? And requires flat files instead? Ditch the project, if at all possible.

Comment: They limit use of their website to pretty much all users  (including the inschool techs. I debated on local files as a solution but I can only see overwritting happening as 700+ will be accessing that file within the same 5 minute span. Mysql isnt exactly a restriction if one of the teachers are willing to buy a web server, but the likelihood of that is unlikely.

Comment: Oh come on. I can literally run a web and db server from my (aging) phone.

Comment: Just because you can't use MySQL doesn't mean you should be using files anyways. Have you considered [SQLite](http://php.net/manual/en/book.sqlite.php)?

Comment: I do have to say I am now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I am tempted to reject the premiss of the question like some commenters have, here's an answer (I'm shamelessly trying to earn 200 reputation to try to help get a new site launched):

Write a recordVote function that **stores each vote in its own file** in a directory **using a unique id in the file name** (PHP doesn't have one guaranteed to yield truly unique GUIDs on all platforms, so use something like https://gist.github.com/dahnielson/508447).

When the polls close, run a tallyVote routine to compile the count of votes by reading all files in the directory.